# How to get all the Posts from a User

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a User and Post scaffolded in my rails application.  I wanted to get all of the posts associated with a user.  For example, I want to be able to do something like this:

> localhost:3000/users/1/posts

And it should give me all of the posts with the user_id = 1.  I know how to get all the posts via the rails console for a specific user. I was just wondering how i can accomplish something like the example above. Would I have to add another method in the users controller?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it without adding new action. Like this:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @posts = @user.posts
  end
end
```

Comment: i am getting this error: No route matches [GET] "/users/1/posts"  .  do i have to add this mapping to the routes.rb?

Comment: You are using nested route so i expect you would like to present list of posts for specific user so you have to put this to PostsController and index action.

Comment: aha ok yes you have to define the posts resorces uder the users resources in routes.rb http://bit.ly/aFFgpE

Answer (score 3):

another **one line example** is the following, add this to your index

```
@posts = User.find(params[:user_id]).posts
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a longish answer to a related question that may be helpful:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17911920/321583